# Function to evaluate columns with different names within a data frame

Tags: r, function

I have a data frame (total) like so:

```
            ID      pos  ori cont mA1 nmA1 bdA1 mA2 nmA2 bdA2 mB1 nmB1 bdB1 mB2
         1: ChrM      5   +  CCG   0    1    2   0    1    2   0    4    5   0
         2: ChrM      6   +  CGT   0    1    2   2    0    0   2    2    2   1
         3: ChrM      7   -  CGG   0    1    2   0    6    7   0    3    4   1
         4: ChrM     10   +  CGA   0    2    3   2    1    2   2    3    2   1
         5: ChrM     11   -  CGA   0    1    2   2    6    2   0    3    4   1
        ---                                                                   
    164264: ChrM 366914   +  CAA   0    1    2   0    2    3   0    1    2   0
    164265: ChrM 366918   +  CCG   0    1    2   0    2    3   0    0    1   0
    164266: ChrM 366919   +  CGG   0    1    2   0    2    3   0    0    1   0
    164267: ChrM 366920   -  CGG   1    2    2   0    5    6   0    1    2   0
    164268: ChrM 366921   -  CCG   0    3    4   0    3    4   0    0    1   0
            nmB2 bdB2
         1:    5    6
         2:    6    3
         3:    3    2
         4:    7    3
         5:    8    3
        ---          
    164264:    8    9
    164265:    7    8
    164266:    7    8
    164267:    4    5
    164268:    4    5
```

And I want a function to evaluate a couple of criteria. When doing it one by one I used

```
total$critA <- as.numeric((total$mA1+total$nmA1>=4)&(total$nmA1>=bdA1))
```

So I get a 0 if True or 1 if false. I'd like to apply this to all treatments (A1 (m, nm and bd), A2, A3, etc.)

I'm really new to R, and haven't figured out how to do a bunch of stuff just yet, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Check out the `apply` family of functions: https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/

Comment: Also, just making sure you know you will get a 1 if True, 0 if False (not vice versa as you state in your question).

Comment: You're right Gregor, it's the other way around, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll be sure to check it out @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this: (If you share data with `dput` I'd copy/paste it and test... [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) for other tips on writing good, reproducible R questions.

```
add_crit = function(data, treatment) {
    m_name = paste0("m", treatment)
    nm_name = paste0("nm", treatment)
    bd_name = paste0("bd", treatment)
    crit_name = paste0("crit", treatment)

    data[crit_name] = as.numeric(
      (data[m_name] + data[nm_name] >= 4) & (data[nm_name] >= data[bd_name])
    )
    return(data)
}

treatments = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2")
data_with_crit = total

for (trt in treatments) {
    data_with_crit = add_crit(data_with_crit, trt)
}
```

I build up the column names you need as strings with `paste`. When you have column names stored in variables, you need to use `[` rather than `$`, but otherwise they work just as well.

```
fortunes::fortune(343)
```

> Sooner or later most R beginners are bitten by this all too convenient shortcut. As an R newbie,
>       think of R as your bank account: overuse of `$`-extraction can lead to undesirable consequences.
>       It's best to acquire the `'[['` and `'['` habit early.
>          -- Peter Ehlers (about the use of $-extraction)
>             R-help (March 2013)

The other (more generalizable) way to handle this problem would be to "melt" your data into long format - you would have a single `treatment` column with values `A1, A2, ...` and then single columns for `m`, `nm`, `bd`, `crit`. Multiple rows per id (one row per treatment per id). That would lend itself to a `data.table` or `dplyr` solution. Perhaps someone else will post an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help!